# Simple Lock-Free Stack

Tags: java, stack, lock-free

Recently have found such java-concurrency interview task:

> Write simple lock-free Stack with two methods: push and pop.

I made the concent:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;


public class Stack {
    private AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(-1);
    private Object[] data = new Object[1000];

    public void push(Object o) {
        int c = count.incrementAndGet();
        data[c] = o;
    }

    public Object pop() {
        Object top;
        int c;
        while (true) {
            c = count.get();
            if (c == -1) return null;
            top = data[c];
            if (count.compareAndSet(c, c-1))
                return top;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it similar to approach was expected? Or "lock-free stack" means something different? Please, help a java-interview newbie.

Comment: This is an incorrect sample it could  happen that the sequence is handled in the following order:
1) push: c = count.incrementAndGet()
2) pop: c = count.get();
3) pop: top = data[c]
4) data[c] = o
So you get an old or uninitialised value.
This is lock free but not correct/robust

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've certainly started in the right direction, thinking about using Java's atomic integer and atomic functions. That would thus be a lock-free stack, as in: there are no explicit locks.

It is still not correct when concurrently accessed, however, and it's relatively simple to demonstrate that: imagine your push() thread blocks between getting the count and adding the new element to the stack (data[c] = o), and in the meantime a pop() thread comes along, gets the higher count, and pops... What? Whatever happens to be in memory at that location in the stack, but not the Object o (because it wasn't yet inserted).

And that's the problem with lock-free, array-backed stacks, that you have two things you theoretically need to adjust, the count and the content of that particular cell, and you can't do both atomically at the same time. I'm not aware of any lock-free array-backed stack algorithm out there.

There are linked-list-backed stack algorithms though that are lock-free, because in that case you can create a new node, assign it the content, and you only have one operation to execute atomically: change the top pointer.

If you're interested in the argument, the best literary work is Shavit and Herlihy's "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming", which describes lots of different data structures, both lock-free and lock-based. I can't find any paper right now describing the "usual" lock-free stack algorithm in detail, though Maged Michael mentions it in [his SMR paper](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/ieeetpds-2004.pdf), page 8, point 4.2, and I have done [a C99 implementation](https://dev.longitekk.com/Rig/browser/trunk/src/rig_stack.c) myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class LockFreeStack {

public static void main(String... args) {
    LFStack<String> stack = new LFStack<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new RandomStackUse(stack));
        t.setName("My stack thread " + i);
        t.start();
    }
}

private static class LFStack<E> {
    private volatile AtomicReference<Node<E>> head = new AtomicReference<Node<E>>();

    public E peek() {
        E payload = null;
        Node<E> node = head.get();
        if (node != null) { payload = node.payload; }
        return payload;
    }

    public E pop() {
        E payload;
        while (true) {
            Node<E> oldHeadNode = head.get();
            if (oldHeadNode == null) { return null; }
            payload = head.get().payload;
            if (head.compareAndSet(oldHeadNode, oldHeadNode.next.get())) { break; }
            //System.out.println("Retry");
        }
        return payload;
    }

    public void push(E e) {
        Node<E> oldHeadNode = new Node<E>(e);

        while (true) {
            Node<E> oldRootNode = head.get();
            if (oldRootNode != null) { oldHeadNode.next.set(oldRootNode); }
            if (head.compareAndSet(oldRootNode, oldHeadNode)) { break; }
            //System.out.println("Retry");
        }
    }
}


//to be used as LinkedList chain <Node> => <Node> => <Node> => null
private static class Node<E> {
    private E payload;
    private AtomicReference<Node<E>> next;

    public Node(E e) {
        payload = e;
        next = new AtomicReference<Node<E>>();
    }
}

public static class RandomStackUse implements Runnable {
    private LFStack<String> stack;
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public RandomStackUse(LFStack<String> stack) {this.stack = stack;}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long counter = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (rand.nextInt() % 3 == 0) {
                stack.push(String.valueOf(counter++));
                //System.out.println(String.format("%s pushed %d", Thread.currentThread().getName(), counter));
            }
            if (rand.nextInt() % 3 == 1) {
                String value = stack.pop();
                //System.out.println(String.format("%s pop %s", Thread.currentThread().getName(), value));
            }
            if (rand.nextInt() % 3 == 2) {
                String value = stack.peek();
                //System.out.println(String.format("%s peek %s", Thread.currentThread().getName(), value));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think there's a mistake here:

```java
Node<E> oldHeadNode = head.get();
if (oldHeadNode == null) { return null; }
payload = head.get().payload;
```

It would be better to call `head.get()` only once because otherwise you could get a null if another thread calls pop in between the two calls to `head.get()`

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyConcurrentStack<T>
{
private AtomicReference<Node> head = new AtomicReference<Node>();
public MyConcurrentStack()
{

}

public void push(T t)
{
    Node<T> n = new Node<T>(t);
    Node<T> current;

    do
    {
        current = head.get();
        n.setNext(current);
    }while(!head.compareAndSet(current, n));
}

public T pop()
{
    Node<T> currentHead = null;
    Node<T> futureHead = null;
    do
    {
        currentHead = head.get();
        if(currentHead == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        futureHead = currentHead.next;
    }while(!head.compareAndSet(currentHead, futureHead)); 

    return currentHead.data;
}

public T peek()
{
    Node<T> n = head.get();
    if(n==null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return n.data;
    }
}

private static class Node<T>
{
       private final T data;
       private Node<T> next;

       private Node(T data)
       {
           this.data = data;
       }

       private void setNext(Node next)
       {
           this.next = next;
       }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyConcurrentStack m = new MyConcurrentStack();
    m.push(12);
    m.push(13);
    m.push(15);

    System.out.println(m.pop());
    System.out.println(m.pop());
    System.out.println(m.pop());
    System.out.println(m.pop());
}
}
```

The code is self explanatory. Please let me know if anybody needs explanation. 
The stack is formed as per the following diagram:

```
  ...     ...      ...
 |   |-->|   | -->|   |
  ...     ...      ...

   ^
   |
current head
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#drainTo%28java.util.Collection%29) Use method put() to insert the element and method drainTo(Collection c) to get elements. Then read elements from the end of c.